# awk combine unique values of other columns based on the unique values of a single column

Tags: csv, awk

My input file looks like

```
Item1,200,a,four,five,six,seven,eight1,nine1
Item2,500,b,four,five,six,seven,eight2,nine2
Item3,900,c,four,five,six,seven,eight3,nine3
Item2,800,d,four,five,six,seven,eight4,nine4
Item1,,e,four,five,six,seven,eight5,nine5
```

Based on the unique values of first column, I want to combine the unique values of all other columns.
What I tried so far is:

```
awk -F, '{
a[$1]=a[$1]?a[$1]"_"$2:$2;
b[$1]=b[$1]?b[$1]"_"$3:$3;
c[$1]=c[$1]?c[$1]"_"$4:$4;
d[$1]=d[$1]?d[$1]"_"$5:$5;
e[$1]=e[$1]?e[$1]"_"$6:$6;
f[$1]=f[$1]?f[$1]"_"$7:$7;
g[$1]=g[$1]?g[$1]"_"$8:$8;
h[$1]=h[$1]?h[$1]"_"$9:$9;
}END{for (i in a)print i, a[i], b[i], c[i], d[i], e[i], f[i], g[i], h[i];}' OFS=, input.txt
```

the output from above is:

```
Item3,900,c,four,five,six,seven,eight3,nine3
Item1,200_,a_e,four_four,five_five,six_six,seven_seven,eight1_eight5,nine1_nine5
Item2,500_800,b_d,four_four,five_five,six_six,seven_seven,eight2_eight4,nine2_nine4
```

but what I am expecting is:

```
Item3,900,c,four,five,six,seven,eight3,nine3
Item1,200,a_e,four,five,six,seven,eight1_eight5,nine1_nine5
Item2,500_800,b_d,four,five,six,seven,eight2_eight4,nine2_nine4
```

I am looking for some help on:

1. How to take only the unique values while combining the values?
2. Whenever a blank value is present, the delimiter (underscore in my case above) shouldn't be appended at the end while combining?
3. How to sort the output based on column-1 values?

thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: When you say "unique values" - do you mean unique for a given $1 or unique for a given field for a given $1? For example if the value "ten" was present in 2 different fields for Item1 - would it appear twice in the output or just once?

Comment: @EdMorton it's unique for a given field for a given $1. Meaning: for each unique Item value (i.e. col-1), concat unique values present under each column

Comment: OK, thx for clarifying. And does it matter which order the unique values are concatenated in? For example if the last value output on the `Item1` line was `nine5_nine1` instead of `nine1_nine5` is that OK?

Comment: @EdMorton sorting on col-1 is enough. For remaining columns, any order of values is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With any `awk` plus `sort`:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
{
    key = $1
    keys[key]
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ( ($i ~ /[^[:space:]]/) && (!seen[key,i,$i]++) ) {
            idx = key FS i
            vals[idx] = (idx in vals ? vals[idx] "_" : "") $i
        }
    }
}
END {
    for (key in keys) {
        printf "%s%s", key, OFS
        for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
            idx = key FS i
            printf "%s%s", vals[idx], (i<NF ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file | sort -t, -k1,1
Item1,200,a_e,four,five,six,seven,eight1_eight5,nine1_nine5
Item2,500_800,b_d,four,five,six,seven,eight2_eight4,nine2_nine4
Item3,900,c,four,five,six,seven,eight3,nine3
```

or with GNU `awk` for arrays of arrays (see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Multidimensional and https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Arrays-of-Arrays for the difference between the two) and `sorted_in` (see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Controlling-Array-Traversal and https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Controlling-Scanning):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
{
    for ( i=2; i<=NF; i++ ) {
        vals[$1][i][$i]
    }
}
END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
    for ( key in vals ) {
        printf "%s%s", key, OFS
        for ( i=2; i<=NF; i++ ) {
            sep = ""
            for ( val in vals[key][i] ) {
                if ( val ~ /[^[:space:]]/ ) {
                    printf "%s%s", sep, val
                    sep = "_"
                }
            }
            printf "%s", (i<NF ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Item1,200,a_e,four,five,six,seven,eight1_eight5,nine1_nine5
Item2,500_800,b_d,four,five,six,seven,eight2_eight4,nine2_nine4
Item3,900,c,four,five,six,seven,eight3,nine3
```

Comment: thank you for the script @Ed Morton. Could you please explain a bit on the logic that is going on in your script? Being new to awk syntax and especially the arrays concept appears tricky and super powerful, I am trying to understand: `1. What's happening with seen[key,i,$i] --> is it like the $i value is being added to 'seen' array at index location [key,i]...? Isn't it becoming multi-dimensional array by doing so? 2. How does "@ind_str_asc" help in sorting the records based on col-1 value? `

Comment: Whenever you see an array named `seen[]` in an awk script it's idiomatically being used for 1 purpose - to test whether or not whatever is being used as its index at that point has occurred previously. It's always used in the context of a test+postincrement like `seen[foo]++` because the first time "foo" occurs the value of `seen[foo]` is zero (a false condition), then incrementing it sets it to 1 so that the 2nd time "foo" occurs the value of `seen[foo]` is non-zero (a true condition). So `if (!seen[key,i,$i]++)` says `if the index created from key, i, and $i has not previously occurred`.

Comment: I added links to the GNU manual that'll explain the difference between pseudo-multi-dimensional arrays (as supported by all awks) and arrays of arrays aka true multi-dimensional arrays (as only supported by GNU awk) and what the pre-defined sorting strings mean. If you're not sure what anything is doing or what values variables have you can always add "print" statements throughout the code to tell you want's happening to all the variables' values.

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT:*** Adding solution with more sensible variable names.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
}
{
  first_field_value[$1]
  for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i!=""){
      split(field_values[$1,i],temp_array,"_")
      delete column_value
      for(p in temp_array){
        column_value[temp_array[p]]
      }
      if(!($i in column_value)){
        (field_values[$1,i] == "" ? "" : field_values[$1,i] "_")$i
      }
    }
  }
  tot_field=tot_field>NF?tot_field:NF
}
END{
  for(ind in first_field_value){
    printf "%s,",ind;
    for(j=2;j<=tot_field;j++){
      printf("%s%s",field_values[ind,j],j==tot_field?ORS:OFS)
    }
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
Item3,900,c,four,five,six,seven,eight3,nine3
Item1,200,a_e,four,five,six,seven,eight1_eight5,nine1_nine5
Item2,500_800,b_d,four,five,six,seven,eight2_eight4,nine2_nine4
```

***Explanation:*** This is my previous code's explanation; which had less sensible variable names, but still this explanation could be read for understanding purposes.

```
awk '                                          ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                                         ##Starting BEGIN section.
  FS=OFS=","                                   ##Setting FS and OFS as comma here.
}
{
  b[$1]                                        ##Creating array b which has index $1, basically to keep track of $1 values as index here.
  for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){                          ##Running for loop from i=2 to till value of NF here.
    if($i!=""){                                ##Checking if any field is NOT NULL then do following.
      num=split(c[$1,i],d," ")                 ##Splitting array c with index of $1,i and splitting its value to array d; it also saves number of elements in array d to variable num here.
      for(p=1;p<=num;p++){                     ##Running a for loop from p=1 to value of num.
        e[d[p]]                                ##Creating array e whose index is value of array d which are actually values of fields and I am making sure duplicate values will NOT come by this array.
      }
      if(!($i in e)){                          ##If current field is not present in array e then do following.
        a[$1,i]=(a[$1,i]?a[$1,i] "_":"")$i     ##Creating array a with index of $1,i and keep concatenating its value to it.
      }
      c[$1,i]=(c[$1,i]?c[$1,i] OFS:"")$i       ##Creating array c with current field value and keep concatenating it; array c is the one which STOPS values to re-enter OR let us say it DO NOT allow duplicates values in array a.
    }
  }
  tot_field=tot_field>NF?tot_field:NF          ##Creating variable tot_field which will let us know till what value we need to run loop in END BLOCK of this code.
}
END{
  for(k in b){                                     ##Starting a for loop which traverse through array b here.
    printf "%s,",k;                                ##Printing its index here which is basically first field of all lines.
    for(j=2;j<=tot_field;j++){                     ##Running for loop till value of Maximum field value.
      printf("%s%s",a[k,j],j==tot_field?ORS:OFS)   ##Printing value of array a whose index is  k and j where k is index of array b(1st field) and j is field number starts from 2.
    }
  }
}
'  Input_file                                      ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210562/discussion-on-answer-by-ravindersingh13-awk-combine-unique-values-of-other-colum).